# Is there a c.ended(iter) method compatible with range-based for-loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, range

If I understand right, range-based for-loops check the end condition by calling iter != c.end() on your iterator (iter) and collection (c).  But suppose I have a collection where generating the iterator to c.end() is not particularly easy or efficient?

Can range-based for-loops recognize another method (something like `bool c.ended(iter) const`) which will take iter as an argument and check if it has reached the end?  Is there some trick with templates to get the same effect?

EXAMPLE:

Imagine we have a forward_list that has a header/end node to mark the end, but it doesn't hold a pointer to that node.  Instead, it has some method by which it recognizes the node when it's reached.  Then, we can't easily create an iterator which points to that node, but if an iterator already does point to that node, we can tell.

EXAMPLE 2:

Ok, clearly example 1 was bad.  I'll get closer to what I'm actually doing (although there's a little more).  forward_list can be frustrating because it has no erase() method.  There's only an erase_after().  So, to rectify this I want to have an alternate forward_list where the iterator internally contains a pointer to the node prior to the one it claims to point to.  Now I can have an erase() method which behaves properly (at the expense of having to worry about whether something else might erase the node I'm internally sitting on).  Now generating an iterator to end() involves figuring out what's the very last element in the list.  I could maintain a pointer, but that's really just wasted wasted memory because checking if the iterator==end() should be easy. I can just check if p_my_node -> next == NULL.

Comment: How would something other than `end()` be used to check the end of the container? If that is cheaper than `end()`, why is `end()` not implemented in terms of that? Or maybe you are under the misconception that the range based for loop will call `end()` for each iteration?

Comment: The call to `end()` will be "cached" equivalently to `auto __begin = c.begin(), __end = c.end()` (if you container provides `begin()` and `end()` member functions). The type will be deduced from the `c.begin()` call, not from the `c.end()` call.

Comment: Actually, I did think it would call end() for each iteration.  But the point is I want to implement a method c.ended(iter) which returns a boolean if iter is at the end.  In that case, I don't need to figure out how to generate an iterator which points to the end

Comment: @dspyz: You will have to describe the motivation for that, as I don't seem to grasp the core issue you are trying to solve with this approach.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I proposed in the answer. Take the time to read over the approach and if it is not clear ask what you don't understand. The solution proposed trivially matches both examples. In particular `ptr->isEnd()` can be rewritten as `ptr->next == nullptr;` for your second example.

Comment: The advanced example is still not a good one: you can still store a null pointer for the `end` and implement your comparison something like `bool operator==(It const& i0, It const& i1) { return i0.node? (i1.node? i0.node == i1.node: !i0.node->next): (i1.node? !i1.node->next: true); }` (actually, this is just a rewrite of David's answer; well, at least, it should be)

Comment: That said, however, there is some discussion of supporting _sentinel-based sequences_: for algorithms taking ForwardIterators (or weaker) the algorithm would take different types for the begin and the end position. This way, a comparison between an iterator and the end position could short circuit the check whether positions are at the end and just evaluate the moral equivalent of `c.ended(it)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of the range-based for loop must only call the `end()` function on the container once, so if that is your concern, it has already been addressed in the standard.

If you have anything other than `c.end()` that can be used as a check for *end-of-range*, and is cheaper to calculate than `c.end()`, why is `c.end()` not just that?

---

It may be hard to get the idea through just in English in the comments, but this sketch of an implementation should be able to give you an idea:

```
class Iterator {
   node *ptr;    // nullptr == end() by convention
public:
   Iterator() : ptr() {}
   Iterator(node *ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
   bool isEnd() const {
      return !ptr || ptr->isEnd();
   }
   friend bool operator==(Iterator const& lhs, Iterator const& rhs) {
      return (lhs.isEnd() && rhs.isEnd())
          || (lhs.ptr == rhs.ptr);
   } 
};
```

Now the implementation of `end()` is a cheap implementation:

```
Iterator Container::end() {
   return Iterator();
}
```

Comment: Because I need access to the iterator itself to know whether it's at the end.  I can't just generate what an end() iterator looks like

Comment: As an example, imagine a forward_list that doesn't internally hold a pointer to the header(/end) node, but can recognize that node when it sees it

Comment: @dspyz: you `end()` is _not_ the last node but where you arrive when incrementing past the last node. For a `std::forward_list<T>` I would expect `end()` to just hold a null pointer which trivial to get hold of.

Comment: It's a dummy header node.  Not a null-pointer.  I know you can use a null-pointer, but in this case I'm suggesting what if you don't.  This is meant to be an example.  My actual data-structure is quite a bit more complicated

Comment: "check for end-of-range" and "iterator to end-of-range" are not the same thing.  The first takes an iterator and returns a boolean.  The second takes no arguments and returns an iterator for whom other iterators must have a compatible != method.

Comment: @dspyz: I don't see the problem here... just create an iterator that points to that *header node* and return it in `end()`. Other alternatives (when there is no *header node* that you can refer to) include tracking whether an iterator is *end* by checking either an internal flag or a condition. That is used for example in `istream_iterator<T>`, where a default constructed iterator has an internal flag marking it as *end*, and an iterator holding a real stream is considered *end* if the stream is in an invalid state. The comparison checks either the flag or the condition.

Comment: But how can I create an iterator that points to the header node if I don't have any pointer or reference to the header node already?

Comment: @dspyz: You have a way of testing whether an iterator is referring to the *header node*, and you can create an iterator that refers to *nothing* an implement a comparison that will determine both to be *equal*

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution could be to create a special kind of iterator for `c.end()` and then make `your_iterator::operator==()` call `c.ended(iter)` and return that value when it sees end iterator as argument. I think you can create special overloaded `operator==` for different iterator type (end iterator), but if that a good solution difficult to say in advance. But you can have a special flag or special value in the end iterator and have that behavior in runtime in `operator==()`.

Comment: Using a different type for the past-the-end iterator (`end()`) and other iterators leads to problems with the Standard Library. It is often assumed, e.g. in algorithms and the range-based for loop, that they have the same type.

Comment: @DyP good to know thanks, but runtime check should work I believe.

Comment: Yes, I could do funky things with operator== and operator!=, but conceptually I don't see any reason why iterator's operator== or operator!= should have anything to do with the end-of-collection check.  That's why it seemed like C++ should have a c.ended() method I can implement instead

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying.  Actually that's a good idea, because it can figure out at compile-time which version of operator!= is being called.

Comment: @dspyz: If it can be checked at compile time, then it is a different type. Different types for `begin()` and `end()` are not supported in the language. The behavioral expansion of the loop contains: `auto __begin = begin-expr, __end = end-expr;`, those are two variables of the same type.